# Export to Excel for Tree Structured Table

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Hello Community Members,

I am implementing Export to Excel functionality for one of the SAP Fiori app which has tree structured data in tabular format.

[Tree Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfYaw.jpg)

I tried implementing with ExportTypeCSV approach but it shows in linear format without tree structure.

Below is the code.

```
exportToExcel: function(table, oModel)
{
        var cols = table.getColumns();      
        var items = table.getRows();

         var cellId = null;     
         var cellObj = null;        
         var cellVal = null;        
         var headerColId = null;        
         var headerColObj = null;       
         var headerColVal = null;       
         var column = null;

         var json = {}; var colArray = []; var itemsArray= [];

         //push header column names to array        
         for(var j=0; j<cols.length;j++){

                column = "";            
                column = cols[j];

                headerColId = column.getId();       
                headerColObj = sap.ui.getCore().byId(headerColId);      
                headerColVal = headerColObj.getLabel().getText();

                if(headerColObj.getVisible()){      
                    json={name: headerColVal};      
                    colArray.push(json);

                }       
            }       
            itemsArray.push(colArray);

          //push table cell values to array

          for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {      
              colArray = [];        
              cellId = "";   cellObj = "";  cellVal = "";       
              headerColId = null; headerColObj = null; headerColVal = null;

              var item = items[i];

                for(var j=0; j<cols.length;j++){        
                    cellId = item.getAggregation("cells")[j].getId();       
                    cellObj = sap.ui.getCore().byId(cellId);

                    if(cellObj.getVisible()){

                        if(cellObj instanceof sap.m.Text ||cellObj instanceof sap.m.Label ||cellObj instanceof sap.m.Link) {                                    
                            cellVal = cellObj.getText();
                        }

                        if(cellObj instanceof sap.m.HBox){                                  
                            cellVal = cellObj.getItems()[0].getText();
                        }

                        if(cellObj instanceof sap.m.ObjectNumber){                                  
                            var k = cellObj.getUnit();      
                            cellVal = cellObj.getNumber()+" "+k;

                        }

                        if(cellObj instanceof sap.m.ObjectIdentifier){                                  
                            var objectIdentifierVal = "";

                            if(cellObj.getTitle() != undefined && cellObj.getTitle() != "" && cellObj.getTitle() != null )      
                                objectIdentifierVal = cellObj.getTitle();

                            if(cellObj.getText() != undefined && cellObj.getText() != "" && cellObj.getText() != null )     
                                objectIdentifierVal = objectIdentifierVal+" "+cellObj.getText();        

                            cellVal = objectIdentifierVal;      
                        }       
                        if(cellObj instanceof sap.ui.core.Icon){                                    
                            if(cellObj.getTooltip() != undefined && cellObj.getTooltip() != "" && cellObj.getTooltip() != null )        
                            cellVal = cellObj.getTooltip();     
                        }       
                        if(j==0){       
                            json={ name:  "\r"+cellVal};        
                        }       
                        else        
                        {       
                            json={ name:  cellVal};     
                        }       
                        colArray.push(json);        
                    }       
                }       
                itemsArray.push(colArray);
            }

         //export json array to csv file

          var oExport = new sap.ui.core.util.Export({

                exportType: new sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV({

                    separatorChar: ","

                }),                     

                models: oModel,

                rows: {     
                    path: "/"       
                },

                // column definitions with column name and binding info for the content     
                columns: [itemsArray]       
            });

          oExport.saveFile().always(function() {        
                this.destroy();     
            });
}
```

Any pointers for achieving tree type formatting in excel will be very helpful.

Thanks,

Saurabh

Comment: Could you post some code for us to debug? Without more information this question is too broad to reasonably answer.

Comment: @Adam - Thanks for quick response. I edited my post with more information now by adding code and tree table image in the application.

Comment: I’m trying to understand the coding.
Are you inserting leading spaces into the first column before your description, to indicate the different hierarchy levels?
Is it possible, that leading spaces are ignored by excel?
Maybe you might start your description cell with something like a “.”-character, followed by spaces?

How about simulating the tree structure by putting the description in different columns, according to their hierarchy level?

Comment: @SAPFioriCrew - Thanks for response. I am able to put leading space with some special characters like '>' but want to add here that table is dynamic. Like, for first element it may have five child nodes, for second element it may have three nodes. So, how to get exact tree structure rendered? And how placing of description  to different column can help, please explain.

Comment: From your picture it seems that the tree structure is only seen in the very first column “Description”. For every item in the “Description”- column you have its hierarchy level in the tree? This is the important information you need to have. If you look at [this example](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.TreeTable.ODataAnnotationsTreeBinding/preview) and expand all its nodes manually you see their hierarchy level (0, 1, 2).

Comment: For every item in your “Description”- column you just add as many leading spaces as given by its hierarchy level before its description text. This gives you a tree structure in the very first column. Instead of adding leading spaces in the very first column, you might also enter the description text in the next column. So in your picture you will put “Assets” in the first column, first row. Again “Assets” in second column, second row. “Current assets” in third column, third row. And so on